Condensation in ceiling when attic door is open
I opened up my attic today to run some cabling for security cameras and I noticed significant condensation on the ceiling. When I closed the attic door it went away.
Should I be concerned? What is happening here?



Almost looks like joists shadows, cause by dust/dirt collecting on slightly damper/colder sections where joists are, but they built up after time.  Wonder if the same process, but the paint/finish darkens due to temp/humidly changes.

You'd have to tell us a bit about your climate and recent weather. It would also help to know something about the house, such as attic and ventilation types. With what we know we can only make wild guesses.

You've tagged HVAC, but I don't see how that's relevant. Is there equipment up there? You'd also want to mention that in your question post. Please take the [tour] and see [ask], then revise your post to add information.

If your interior is air conditioned to a low temperature, hot humid air came down from the attic and the higher concentration of humidity condensed on the colder interior surfaces.  Being concentrated on those places where the cold was backed with denser materials.   I would check the venting and air circulation in the attic and also check to see if there was a leak that wet insulation creating more humidity.
